# passing 2 different models from 2 different apps to another app table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

app1/model

```
class Deployment(models.Model):
  uid = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  target = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

app2/model

```
class AccountRecord(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  national_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
```

app3/views.py

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = AccountRecord
    template_name = "tableview/table_view.html"
    paginate_by = 25

 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['deployment'] = Deployment.objects.all()
    return context
```

app3 html template

```
      <table class="table card-table table-vcenter text-nowrap">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Deployment</th>
                <th>Account</th>
                <th>National ID</th>
                <th>Filename</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             {% for account in object_list %}
              <tr>
                <td>DEPLOYMENT.NAME HERE!</td>
                <td>{{ account.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.national_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ account.file_name }}</td>
             </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

I am trying to pass data from these 2 model to another apps html template.

with my current app3/views.py the table only show blank column even after i put {{ deployment.name }}

can anyone point out how to do it correctly.

Comment: Where's your `AccountRecord` model?

Comment: @IainShelvington I am sorry there's a typo from me, I've edited it

Comment: `deployment` is a queryset of all `Deployment`s, the queryset doesn't have a `name` attribute. Which deployment do you want to show the name of for each account?

Comment: @IainShelvington in short I just want to show the name data from Deployment model, how can I do that? I am willing to reconstruct all my models and views

Comment: The name of which Deployment though, there are many. There doesn't seem to be any link between the Deployment and AccountRecord models either, so it's not clear what Deployment name you would display for each AccountRecord

Comment: I see, I'll try to link these 2 models with foreign key now